# Wildcard in an if statement

Tags: php

is it possible to use wildcard in an if statement?
My code:

```
*=wildcard
if ($order_info=='Quatro*') {

}
```

$order_info will be "Quatro - na splátky", or "Quatro - čťžýáí"

Comment: `preg_match` will do the trick, or just `strpos($order_info, 'Quatro') === 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, use a regex:

```
if( preg_match( '/^Quatro.*/', $order_info))
{
}
```

Comment: will match 'something else Quatro'

Answer (score 7):

Use [regex](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (preg_match('/^Quatro/', $order_info)) {

}
```

or [strpos](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($order_info, 'Quatro') === 0) {

}
```

**Edit:** Avoiding regex engine invocation for simple string matches like this is usually preferred. `strpos` will do the same job less expensively.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Use `preg_match` or `strpos` instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions will do this](http://php.net/regex).

Or you could do:

```
if($order_info.substr(0, 6) == 'Quatro')
```